# Are Lupus patients typically good candidates for total ankle replacements?

Tags: surgery, arthritis, ankle, lupus, joint-replacements

I was very recently diagnosed with Lupus. But ive always had arthritis problems because i was born with congenital bone fusions so throughout my life I've had a series of surgeries, including a triple arthrodesis on both my feet. Last time I saw my pediatrist, he mentioned that I had a bone spur and that it looked like I was in need of a total ankle replacement and would be a great candidate for it (but this was before i was diagnosed with Lupus). Would the lupus diagnosis change how well a an ankle replacement might work out for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you browse through Pubmed, there are two articles which provide some insights for your question:

1. Shah U, Mandl L, Mertelsmann-Voss C, et al. Systemic lupus erythematosus is not a risk factor for poor outcomes after total hip and total knee arthroplasty. Lupus. 2015;24(9):900-908. doi:10.1177/0961203314566635. [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4504835/)

They have done a case-control study comparing individuals with lupus receiving a total knee arthroplasty to individuals without the conditions also receiving this intervention.

Here are their conclusion:

> While SLE patients have more comorbidities than OA, and SLE THA have
>   worse pre-operative pain and function compared with OA controls, SLE
>   was not an independent risk factor for poor short term pain or
>   function after either hip or knee arthroplasty.

This concerned knee arthroplasty, but obviously it shows some tendency regarding those procedures and the outcomes for patients with SLE

2. Mak A. Orthopedic surgery and its complication in systemic lupus erythematosus. World Journal of Orthopedics. 2014;5(1):38-44. doi:10.5312/wjo.v5.i1.38. [2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3955778/)

They provide a good overview of the complications associated with orthopedic surgery in general for patients with SLE.

Here is an extract:

> complications as a result of surgical procedures are indeed not
>   uncommon. SLE per se and its various associated pharmacological
>   treatments may pose lupus patients to certain surgical risks if they
>   are not properly attended to and managed prior to, during and after
>   surgery. Concerted effort of management and effective communication
>   among orthopedic specialists and rheumatologists play an integral part
>   in enhancing favorable outcome and reduction in postoperative
>   complications for patients with SLE through thorough pre-operative
>   evaluation, careful peri-operative monitoring and treatment, as well
>   as judicious postoperative care.

Both articles are freely available so you can read them to have additional informations.

Hope this helps.